# Getting first and last day of three consecutive month in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the first date and last date of **three consecutive month** *starting from* **current moth and moving towards past**,i.e. if current month is November,my output will be first and last of Nov,followed by first and last date of October,followed by first and last date of September.  I have written the code as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calculatingMonthRange(){
    console.log('calculatingMonthRange() got called');
    var date = new Date();
    var currdate=date;

     for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
         var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
         var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
         console.log('FirstDay='+firstDay+' LastDay='+lastDay+"\n");
         date.setDate(currdate.getDate()-(30*i));
     }
 }
</script>
```

this is the output what I'm getting:::

```
FirstDay=Fri Nov 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) LastDay=Sat Nov 30  2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

FirstDay=Tue Oct 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) LastDay=Thu Oct 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

FirstDay=Thu Aug 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) LastDay=Sat Aug 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

**where is the month September is going????why is it printing August instead of September?????**

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
  function calculatingMonthRange(){
    console.log('calculatingMonthRange() got called');
    var date = new Date();
    var currdate=date;

     for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
         var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
         var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
         console.log('FirstDay='+firstDay+' LastDay='+lastDay+"\n");
         date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() - 1, 1);
     }
  }
```

You can play with the code here: http://jsbin.com/uPaVOXI/1/edit?js,console